# ActionEvent in Override can't find JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, server, chat

I want the "Login" button to close the symbol frame and open a new `JFrame`. But before I work on getting the button to open another `JFrame` I want to see if the button can can close the current frame that's open. I am new to java and this is the first project that I am working on.

I have tried everything that I know of and it still does not work.

Here is some code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;  

class digit implements ActionListener {
    
    private static JLabel userLabel;
    private static JTextField userText;
    private static JLabel passLabel;
    private static JPasswordField passText;
    private static JButton button;
    private static JLabel success;
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
        frame.setSize(300, 170);
        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("appicon.png");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setIconImage(icon);
        
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        userLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);
        
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(userText);
        
        passLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passLabel);
        
        passText = new JPasswordField();
        passText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passText);
        
        button = new JButton("Login");
        button.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        button.addActionListener(new digit());
        panel.add(button);
        
        success = new JLabel();
        success.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(success);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String username = userText.getText();
        String password = passText.getText();
        
        if(username.equals("The8th") && password.equals("Password123")) {
            success.setText("Login Successful!");
            frame.dispose();
        } else {
            success.setText("Invalid Username Or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The entire structure of your code is wrong: 1) class names start with an upper case variable, 2) don't use static variables 3) only the frame is created in the main() method. All the other components should be created in your "Digit" class. 4) Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). The "TextDemo" will show you how to better structure your code.

Comment: Then in your ActionListener. you can just use the `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...)` method to access the frame the button has been added to. The ActionEvent contains the "source" object of the event, in this case the button that was clicked.

Comment: *"open a new JFrame"* The log-in should probably be a modal `JDialog`. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to check this out and use (e.getSource()) instead in case of adding more buttons, also it seems like your whole code seems wrong
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
    if (e.getSource() == button ) { 
        
       //write your executable code here
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == anotherbutton){

        
   //write your executable code here
        
    }
```